# Python: Getting Syntax Error while using Argument of an Exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, syntax-error

I want to use **Argument of an Exception** to show additional information while an error occur in my code.
Here is my code.

**ArgumentOfAnException.py**

```
from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input

def to_celsius(f):
    try:
        c = (f-32)*5/9;
        return c;
    except ValueError, Argument:
        print("The argumet doesn't contain number\n", Argument);
        return;

f = raw_input("Enter temperature in *F : ");
print("Temperature in Celsius : ", to_celsius(float(f)));
print("Thank you...");
```

Here I use ***Argument*** variable to display additional information when error occur in my code but after running the program there will show a ***syntax error*** in the console output and the error is like

```
File "F:\Document\Files\Coding\Java Eclipse\Python Project\First Project\src\Error\ArgumentOfAnException.py", line 7
    except ValueError, Argument:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you're using python 3.x.

Use following syntax (using `as`):

```
except ValueError as Argument:
```

Reference: [`try` statement - Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement)

Comment: Yes I use python 3.4.3